# Cordova failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, java-8

I am on Ubuntu 19.04

I followed this Cordova guide [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#setting-environment-variables)

But when I write "cordova build" in terminal, I get the following output:

> Failed to find 'JAVA_HOME' environment variable. Try setting it manually.

I then do "nano ~/.bashrc" to see that I have this:

> export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241"
>
> export PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"

This is also the jdk that I use in IntelliJ, with no issues at all.

if I type "cordova requirements", I get the following output

> Requirements check results for android:
>
> Java JDK: installed 11.0.7
>
> Android SDK: installed true
>
> Android target: not installed
>
> android: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
>
> Gradle: installed /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle
>
> Some of requirements check failed

So why does it fail to find JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: What is output of `java -version`?

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.7+10-post-Ubuntu-2ubuntu219.10, mixed mode, sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Find your JDK 11.0.7 folder address, and modify your `JAVA_HOME` in the bashrc.
For example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```